# discripencies while compressing a bitmap on Google nexus

Tags: android, nexus-one, nexus-s

I am compressing a bitmap object to OutputStream using **"Compress"** function. Here is my code:

```
try {
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
                                bytes);
                    } else {
                        Message message = handler.obtainMessage(1, "false");
                        handler.sendMessage(message);
                        return;
                    }
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError oom) {
                    System.gc();
                    Message message=handler.obtainMessage(1,"false");
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                    return;
                } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                    System.gc();
                    Message message = handler.obtainMessage(1, "false");
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                    return;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.gc();
                    Message message = handler.obtainMessage(1, "false");
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                    return;
                }
```

when i am running this code on G1 and hero, i am getting a proper output stream( which i later save to a image file on sdcard). But when i test this code on Google nexus, i am getting a blurry image after converting the output stream in an image file.

**FYI**

OS: Android 1.5;
G1 and Hero are on 1.5 OS and nexus is on 2.0

Please help.. is there a known issue in nexus?? or am i doing something wrong??

Answer (score 1):

Check [Game Development for Android: A Quick Primer](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/game-development-for-android-quick.html).

From `Step Three: Carefully Design the Best Game Ever`:

> The problem with texture compression
>   is that different graphics card
>   vendors support different texture
>   formats. The G1 and other MSM7k
>   devices support ATI’s ATITC
>   compression format. The Droid supports
>   PowerVR’s PVRTC format. Nvidia’s
>   Tegra2 platform supports the DXT
>   format. The bad news is, these formats
>   are not compatible. The good news is,
>   all OpenGL ES 2.0 devices (including
>   the Snapdragon-based Nexus One, the
>   OMAP3-based Droid, and Tegra2 devices)
>   support a common format called ETC1.
>   ETC1 isn’t the best texture format (it
>   lacks support for alpha channels), and
>   it isn’t supported on the first
>   generation devices, but it’s the most
>   common format supported (the Android
>   SDK provides a compressor utility (see
>   sdk/tools/etc1tool) and runtime tools
>   for this format).